# How to merge two big data tables based on three columns on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a main big data worksheet (10k rows and 30 columns) with countries and various indexes about them. There are three columns -- geo, time, and nace_r2 -- on the basis of which I would like to merge a new table to the main worksheet.

[A picture of current big data worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ySz7.png)

The minor table also has these three columns -- geo, time, and nace_r2 -- and also has an index column (total_employment_ths), the values of which I would like to be merged to the main table. Some cells of this column have N/As instead of numerical values, but I would also like these to be merged to my main worksheet.

[A picture of the minor table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3nDe.png)

How I would like merging to happen:
If geo, time, and nace_r2 of the rows of two tables are identical, then I would like the value of 'total_employment_ths' to join the big data sheet row from the right side (so this would be 31st column in the big data sheet and, say, the value would be added to the already existing 1st row).
If one of geo, time or nace_r2 values in the rows are not identical, I would like a new row to be created.

[Some idea of how I want it to merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBXYC.png)

Above is the image showing how a couple of values from the minor table's column 'total_employment_ths' were added to the main sheet on the basis of the identical values of columns geo, nace_r2 and time (JP C12 2016 and JP C13 2016) in both data sets. Other cells would be filled in similarly.

I hope I made my problem clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: look into using power query or power pivot, both of these add ins should be able to do this

Comment: see link for more info https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-excel-table-or-range-power-query-67538004-cd12-4b61-9cee-8720db1c7136

Comment: The data in Merged Sheets has collected Row has `JP` in `Jeo` column for related Nace & Time,, is this are you are trying? Since this is not merging Rows but pull data from Sheet to other on Criteria !!

Comment: Sorry, Rajesh. Perhaps the image does not reveal the best what I'm trying to achieve. I think it would be a merge because, as I wrote, if the values of columns geo, nace_r2, or time, were not identical, then I would like a new row to be created. Essentially, all values from the minor data set's column 'total_employment_ths' would be transferred to the major data set. 

Do you think I should delete my image of 'merged data' as it may cause confusion?

Comment: Thanks you, PeterH, for your suggestion. I am now looking into power query and will let you know if I managed to merge the two tables.

Comment: Without access to external tools: I would add a column of "source set", either 1 or 2; put them both one after the other; sort by the 3 keys you mentioned, plus set key; create a column which compares current row to the next - if 3 keys match, then take the next row total_employment_ths; another column - if the 3 keys of previous row match, then 1 ("slated for deletion"); copypasta values of the extra data + deletion col; sort by del col; remove rows where del col = 1 and del col; done.